# vim :find command behaviour differs between "enter" and "tab"

Tags: vim

The behaviour of :find command depends whether I press "enter" or "tab" after ":find pattern"

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

```
mkdir vim_experiment && cd vim_experiment
mkdir sub
touch sub/{riri,fifi,loulou}
vim
```

From within vim:

```
:set path=.,**
:find *ir*<CR>
```

-> E345: Can't find file "*ir*" in path

However:

```
:find *ir*<tab>
```

-> auto complete to "riri". Pressing enter opens the file correctly.

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command-line completion expands your globs but the command itself does not.

After tab-completion, the command gets a fully qualified filename but it only gets `*ir*` if you don't use completion, which is not the name of an existing file.

If you want `:find` (or `:edit`, or `:vsplit`, etc.) to open the file matching `*ir*` you need to expand it first with something like that:

```
:find `find . -name '*ir*'`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Is this mentioned in the documentation ? I looked up `:help find` then jumped to `{file}` which states "Wildcard in {file} are expanded."

Where else should I look for before asking on stackoverflow ?